# Different Volume Level for Headsets and Headphones over Combo Jack

Tags: macos, audio

I have the Sony MDRX10. When I use the cable with the mic, I get lower volume level and distortions at max volume but when I use the headphone only cable, I get much better volume control.

I tried using both cables with my smartphone, and they both produce the same volume. Also, I tested with a portable amplifier connected to my Macbook and then the cable with mic; this gave the same output as the one without the mic.  This makes me think the problem is associated with Mac OS X.

Machine specs: Macbook Pro 13" Mid 2012, Yosemite 10.10.4

[image: mdrx10]

Comment: OK.  So what's your question?  I can guess what your question might be, but I should have to guess.  I encourage you to edit it to include all relevant information, and to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Your headphones come with two different cables:

- one without a microphone
- one with a microphone

The sound quality differs when you use one of these cables, the rest of your setup stays the same. So it is high likely that one of your cables is of low quality or just broken.